# Where and how to search for resources (minerals, crystals, etc.)

Tags: star-conflict

Different resources are used to produce components and enhancements. Though, these resources are hardly met. Few times I've found some ore flying around in the space on missions.

Is there any rule where resources are met the most often?

Answer (score 1):

Resources are found near objects and asteroids and from killing enemies. If you want basic items search in sectors nearest the active faction base, for more advanced items look in sectors rank 10+. Sectors in the middle between the 3 factions is where you'll find the best items.

Comment: Would you be able to share any map with frequent spawn locations?

Comment: @Budda Look for cluster of rocks (or structures). That's it. You can pretty much find anything anywhere, as long as you're in a map in the correct lvl tier. (Lvl for a ressource is written in its tooltip, from what i remember.)

Comment: Also, if farming enemies, be on the look out for convoys. They drop lots of basic resources.